# Set color of quickfix arrow in Vim buffer

Tags: javascript, plugins, vim

When I commit the cardinal sin of using `==` instead of `===`, Vim, or its minions of scripts, opens up the quick fix window with some useful tips. Using [vim-hier](https://github.com/jceb/vim-hier), I have the incorrect line highlighted red. How can I further color the adjacent arrow red?

TL;DR

What I have

[image: Ugly yellow arrow]

What I want

[image: Super Amazing Red Arrow]

Comment: `vim-hier` is not what is adding signs to the left column. What does this?

Comment: Also  you are speaking like yoda. You may want to fix that.

Comment: @ZyX  I did not mean that vim-hier was creating it.

Comment: @romainl I think it's more than self explanatory given that I put two pictures clearly illustrating what I want.

Comment: @puk, `true == something` is bad: that's yoda-speak. You must do `something == true`. Anyway, what you are looking for is the `:hilight` command and the `SignColumn` highlight group I think.

Comment: @romainl Definitely not that group. `SignColumn` is for sign column without signs or where highlighting is not defined. If it was that, *everything* would have red background.

Comment: @puk I did not mean you meant vim-hier was creating it. I mean it is impossible to help without knowing highlighting group used by *that* plugin.

Comment: @romainl yoda speak, I get it now...it's not my code, I always do it the other way also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of tinkering, I finally found it. It's the `Todo` group that did it for me. However, I don't know if this is direct, or if a different group uses it. In any case, it only worked for me if I changed this from within the `.vimrc` file

Comment: An `Error` sign matched as `Todo`? That's weird.

Comment: @romainl perhaps is an `ErrorTodo` group, I just didn't have the patience to go through all the highlight groups that are linked to the `Error` group

Answer (score 0):

That's the `Error` highlight group. You can change it directly in your colorscheme.

Comment: I think your mistaken, it's not `Error`, it's `SpellBad` used by `vim-hier`, but that's NOT what I want to change, it's the yellow arrow to the left. I am fairly certain that does not belong to the `Error` group as `:hi` clearly shows `Error` as being red, whereas the arrow is yellow

Comment: I've changed the `guibg` of `Error` to some blue and it changed the background color of the sign to that blue.

Comment: I just tried changing the `guibg`, `guifg`, `ctermbg` and/or `ctermfg` in both the buffer, and the `.vimrc` file, and it in no way changed the color of the `>>` double arrows

Answer (score 0):

The coloring of the `>>` error marker is more likely down to the Syntastic plugin (since it uses `todo` syntax group to [mark syntax warnings](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt#L141)) as opposed to the Hier plugin (which does not use the ToDo syntax group name to colour its elements). See also a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264635/what-do-these-red-arrows-in-vim-mean) regarding the meaning of Syntastic's  markers.