# What do these red arrows in Vim mean?

Tags: vim, macvim

When editing .pt files (which I've configured to be highlighted as XML) in MacVim, I get these funny little red arrows on the side.

[image: Screenshot]

What do these mean?  What "feature" is this, and where can I find out more information about it?

Comment: I believe this is added by some of your plugins. What plugins do you have installed? It may be Syntastic the one that added these in.

Comment: All the plugins are from [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/README.md#features).

Comment: Syntastic is installed in Janus. Try finding out a way to disable Syntastic while using Janus. :)

Comment: Also. DO NOT USE VIM DISTRIBUTIONS. Bad practice among expert/advanced/experienced Vimmers, and they usually have a very confusing structure. If you-re gonna use Vim I suggest you do it slowly, if you need something then you add it, instead of going with a distribution, which would only slow down your progress with Vim because it adds lots of stuff that you have to learn right away, instead of taking your time. :)

Comment: That's probably some good advice.  Maybe when I get a free day I'll start with a fresh install of Vim and configure it from the ground up.

Comment: If you want to put your comments as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those arrows are most probably added by the [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) plugin, you can probably remove that plugin from executing inside Janus, somehow.

Also, as mentioned in my comments. You should not use Vim distributions, and here's why:

It is considered bad practice, that's one of the big reasons. At least it is from an experienced/advanced/expert Vim user, I don't claim to be any of them, but I'm certainly no beginner. :)

But the most important reason is because it slows you down. In more than one way. It slows you down in the fact that you don't get to know Vim, because you didn't configure it, the distribution did, sure you can usually override their settings, but it's definitely not the same than if you did it yourself.

And in a bigger way perhaps, is because you need to learn everything the plugins do, AT THE SAME TIME. That's no good. This of course changes if you're comfortable with all the plugins before hand.

For example right now, you didn't add those arrows, the distribution did. And so you were confused, because you didn't know about it, but it's still there.

That's just my two cents from the perspective of an adept (if I qualify as that) Vim user.

Answer (score 3):

I don't mean to steal thunder from Eduan, but removing syntastic altogether is probably a bit exagerated as it can be a quite useful plugin.

Instead, you should read syntastic documentation, `:h syntastic`, and look around for the option that deals with "signs".

The advice to drop Janus, on the other hand… I completely back it up.

Comment: No problem, you didn't steal any thunder. :) And yes, there is always the option to configure it to something you like. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a syntax error in the "xmlns:tal" portion of your header (something is funky-looking about that colon compared to the others in your image), although it could also just be that Syntastic is complaining about not properly understanding the .pt suffix (I do not think this is the issue).  From getting Syntastic help (`:h syntastic`), you can find the `:Errors` command, which will try to give you a hint about the reason for the error.  I, for example, had stupidly inserted a new element in a multi-line attribute list and googling led me here.

Of course, uninstalling Syntastic, Janus, or vim will also remove the error indicator, as others have suggested.